# How to limit the amount of memory a spawned program can use in C++

Tags: c++, process

In my c++ program I am going to start other programs. If those programs use over a certain amount of memory, I want my program to kill their processes. How can that be done?

I will probably use execv to start the programs.

Comment: What platform? C++ cannot do this by itself; it does not know the concept of processes. But your platform probably does.

Comment: @Billy Considering he's planning to use execv, my guess is he is under a Unix. But, good point.

Comment: @Etienne: The original question didn't have that tidbit.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming, you're on a POSIX system, you can limit this by calling `setrlimit(2)` after `fork()`. For example:

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    struct rlimit limits;
    limits.rlim_cur = 10000000; // set data segment limit to 10MB
    limits.rlim_max = 10000000; // make sure the child can't increase it again
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, &limits);
    execv(...);
}
```

If your child process attempts to allocate more memory than this, it won't be killed automatically, but it will fail to satisfy memory allocation requests. If the child program chooses to abort in this situation, then it will die. If it chooses to continue, the parent won't be notified of this situation.

Comment: You can just use an integer for the `const struct rlimit*` second parameter?

Comment: +1 for being more complete (and thus more useful) than my answer.

Comment: Before this code, how do I start the program? Does the program get started at the end?

Comment: Right, you use `execv()` or whatever in the normal way to start the child process. The key to remember is to set the limit *after* the `fork()` and *before* the `exec()`.

Comment: What if I want to add in another thing to consider: time. Like say, I want to limit how long programs can use over 10MB of memory. Can this be modified to do that?

Comment: @z-buffer: No, not directly. The `setrlimit()` facility itself does not have the concept of time (except for `RLIMIT_CPU`, which limits the total amount of CPU time the process can use).

Answer (score 5):

Read up on the `setrlimit` function. You probably want something like:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

struct rlimit limits;
limits.rlim_cur = // soft limit
limits.rlim_max = // hard limit
int err = setrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, &limits);
if(err) ...
```

This assumes you're writing for Unix/Linux/BSD/Mac/etc., not Windows... which seems like a good guess since you're using `execv`.

A couple notes: the soft limit (`rlim_cur`) may notify the process that the limit is exceeded. Exceeding the hard limit (`rlim_max`) makes `malloc()` fail, setting `errno` to `ENOMEM`, which usually leads to the process dying.  Read the man page or try it out to see how it works on your system. If the stack outgrows `rlim_max`, you may get a `SIGSEGV` signal.

Generally, only a root process can raise `rlim_max`. A regular process can lower `rlim_max` or set `rlim_cur` to anything in the range between 0 and `rlim_max`.

Answer (score 4):

In Linux, you probably want to use [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit). Don't bother killing the children, though. When they run out of memory, they'll die on their own.