# How to get the pid of a program started with fork and execv

Tags: c++, process, fork, execv

In this program, I start another process with execv.

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    struct rlimit limits;
    limits.rlim_cur = 10000000; // set data segment limit to 10MB
    limits.rlim_max = 10000000; // make sure the child can't increase it again
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, &limits);
    execv(...);
}
```

How do I get the pid of the program that was started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's returned by the `fork()` call in the parent, so you need to capture `fork()`'s return value in a variable.

```
pid_t child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == -1) {
  // fork failed; check errno
}
else if (child_pid == 0) {  // in child
  // ...
  execv(...);
}
else {  // in parent
  // ...
  int child_status;
  waitpid(child_pid, &child_status, 0);  // or whatever
}
```

In the child, the use of `execv()` is irrelevant; that doesn't change the pid.

Answer (score 2):

That's the return value from fork() in the original process...

Answer (score 1):

```
pid_t child;
child = fork();
if (child == 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I recognise that code snippet.

[My answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784595/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-memory-a-spawned-program-can-use-in-c/5784634#5784634) was an *example* of how to use `setrlimit()` in combination with `fork()` and `exec()`. It wasn't intended as a *complete* example, and normally you would save the return value of `fork()` for later use (since it's the pid of the child, which is what you want here).

**Example code is not necessarily complete code.**

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `pid` of the process that is starting this program.

The signature of `fork` function is the following:

```
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t fork(void);
```

and it returns:

- `0` in the child
- `the pid of the child` in the parent
- `-1` if an error ocurred

If you want to get the `pid` of the new process created (the child), you must check if the returned value is greather than `0`.

In your example:

```
pid_t pid = fork()

if (pid == 0) {
    struct rlimit limits;
    limits.rlim_cur = 10000000; // set data segment limit to 10MB
    limits.rlim_max = 10000000; // make sure the child can't increase it again
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, &limits);
    execv(...);
}
else if (pid > 0) {
    /* That's the value of the pid you are looking for */
}
```

This can be confusing, but the thing is that when `fork()` is executed, it creates a child process, so the program kind of splits in two. That's why you must check for the `pid` value and do what you want depending of if you are in the child or in the parent.